# is_readable() only returns true if called at least once before session_start

Tags: php

There is something strange on one of my PHP servers. Other servers show different behaviour. But I don't think this is caused by an environment setting.

I'm starting to believe this is a bug. Has anyone heard of this?

`is_readable()` will only return **true** if you call it at least once before you start the session.

If you start the session first, all `is_readable()` calls return **false**. Though you can still read the file with `readfile()` anyway.

```
<?php
// do session_start() to here and you will get BadBad

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ob_start();

// or do session_start() here and you will also get BadBad
echo is_readable("foo.bar") ? "Good" : "Bad";
// But do session_start() here and you get GoodGood
echo is_readable("foo.bar") ? "Good" : "Bad";
// or even do it here and you will still get GoodGood

echo @++$_SESSION['counter'];   // incrementing number always follow GoodGood or BadBad
readfile("foo.bar");            // the contents also always follow GoodGood or BadBad
?>
```

The incrementing number always shows, so sessions are working fine.

Also the file contents always shows, so the file is readable.

I'm running 32 bit PHP Version 5.3.26 on Windows Server 2012 64 bit with IIS 7.5.

What could it be?

Comment: Try some `clearstatcache()`. Since you're testing the **SAME** file, you'll just be reading the cache entry on the 2nd and subsequent calls.

Comment: Completely different approach to this issue - I use the `SplFileInfo` and `SPLFileObject` routines for all 'these type of file queries' as I suspect they need to work correctly?

Comment: @MarcB I tried putting `clearstatcache()` in between everywhere, but it doesn't change anything. If `session_start()` was first, output is BadBad. If `is_readable()` was first, output is GoodGood. The output is **never** BadGood or GoodBad.

Comment: @RyanVincent Yes, Both `SplFileInfo::openFile()` and `SplFileInfo::isReadable()` work as expected. Unlike `is_readable()` which just works incorrect on this machine. But this doesn't explain it for me yet.

Comment: I suspect that you have run into a 'bug' with PHP. I understand how frustrating and 'time wasting' that is. I develop on 'Windows' and 'deploy' on 'linux'. Like you, I need 'file query' routines that work correctly in both environments. Hence my use of the 'SplFile' routines. They work reliably.

Comment: @RyanVincent Oops. I must have mis-looked. My previous remark was wrong. `SplFileInfo::openFile()` is behaving correct. But `SplFileInfo::isReadable()` is giving the same bad behaviour as `isReadable()`. I'm going to reinstall PHP with the latest stable build.

Comment: I just figured out `fastcgi.impersonate=1` **does** seem to affect this. Setting it to 0, gives the desired result. However, settings it to 1 is recommended on just all the documentation I have ever read on installing PHP on Windows with IIS via FastCGI

Comment: @RyanVincent I just upgraded to the latest 5.3 version (5.3.29) it gives the sames issues. However, please also ready my previous comment.

Comment: What are the results when you run the script: 1) from a command line, 2) From the command line using the `system` command in the web server and 3) in the web server? I suspect the the results may explain what is happening.

Comment: @RyanVincent AFAIK, from command link you cannot really use sessions. So I cannot compare with that. The issue only appears once the session is started before having done is_readable once.